# unix timestamp in microsecond to timestamp with current timezone

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

Currently I am re-designing a database and in this I have to import data from existing Db also.
The issue I am facing is with timestamp conversion. The timestamp is saved in the existing database is in microsecond format which is generated by a JS function so it does not have a timezone information.
However, while importing this data, I have to save date and time in different columns so I have to cast this numeric timestamp to date and time to time alone. However, the time is to be saved in numeric format again to ease out my further calculations. Now when I checked the time stamp, I found the time is offset with the timezone which is distorting the data.

Any suggestion about that?
Code sample is something like:

```
WITH ts AS (SELECT (8*60*60*1000) AS ts)
SELECT  ts AS sample_input_in_ms,
        CAST(to_timestamp(ts/1000) AS TIME) calculated_time,
        (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM cast(to_timestamp(ts/1000) AS TIME)) * 1000) AS calculated_output_in_ms
FROM ts;
```

Here, the time used for the example is 08:00:00
The output generated is

```
sample_input_in_ms     calculated_time     calculated_output_in_ms
28800000               17:00:00            61200000
```

**Please note here that JST have offset of +09:00 hrs**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, convert it to a `timestamp without time zone`:

```
to_timestamp(usval / 1000000.0) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
```

Then you can cast that value to `date` and `time` to get the respective parts.

I would *not* split the timestamp into parts, and I would *not* convert the time to fractional days, lest I forgo the power of date arithmetic.